# Flutter Doctor : Xcode installation is incomplete

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build, simulator

I have an app created with Flutter want to build it in IOS.
When i want to run simulator or build the I get error ,When I run Flutter doctor I get this error L

```
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably miss the xcode command line tools, you may want to reinstall XCode, or select the xcode command line tools with the command `xcode-select`

Here's a full fix that should solve your problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6308#issuecomment-257812324

Comment: thanks ,I get this error :xcode-select: error: --switch must be run as root (e.g. `sudo xcode-select --switch <xcode_folder_path>`).

Comment: Yes, you need to make this command as root, as they said.

Comment: as I new MacOS user I don't know how to do that ,can you tell me how I make this command as root

Comment: Simply put `sudo` before using the command, as they wrote the full command will be : `sudo xcode-select --switch <xcode_folder_path>`

Answer (score 99):

I was facing the same issue. I did not installed Xcode from Apple Store. If your scenario is same, you can try below steps,

1. Open Xcode
2. Go to Preferences -> Location tab
3. You will find "Command Line Tools" option. If it is blank, select the Xcode version from list (see image below). It will ask for password or Touchid to update it.
4. Run **flutter doctor** again. It should resolve the issue

[image]

Comment: iphone was also not detected. After this, detected and flutter doctor issues solved!

Answer (score 10):

If you already have Xcode and this happens. Just run this command

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

And

```
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

It will automatically show

Answer (score 7):

So, I was facing this same issue, and tried to and copy paste the command already given. Namely

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

But why did it not work? Silly mistake of mine: I have two Xcode versions in my Applications folder. One is called `Xcode_12_3_0` and the other `Xcode_12_5_1`. Make sure that, when you run the command, you also make sure you enter **your app's real name**. For instance:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_12_5_1.app/Contents/Developer
```

An answer for us, absent-minded people.